# Обрезается строка отправленая с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Есть строка

```
$data_string = '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled": false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Замовити документи",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Документ",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"in_developing"
            },
            {
              "title":"Документ",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"in_developing"
            },
            {
              "title":"Документ",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"in_developing"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title":"Взаємодія з сайтом",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
                "title":"Пошук в ЄДРСР",
                "type":"postback",
                "payload" : "search_edrsr"
            },
            {
                "title":"Статус замовлення",
                "type":"postback",
                "payload" : "status_order"
            },
            {
                "title":"Авторизація",
                "type":"postback",
                "payload" : "authorization"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
            "title":"Оцінити бота",
            "type":"postback",
            "payload" : "rate_bot"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';
```

CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Приходит только:

> { "persistent_menu":[ { "locale":"default", "composer_input_disabled":
>   false, "call_to_actions":[ { "title":"Замовити документи",
>   "type":"nested", "call_to_actions":[ { "title":"Документ",
>   "type":"postback", "payload":"in_developing" }, { "title":"Документ",
>   "type":"postback", "payload":"in_developing" }, { "title":"Документ",
>   "type":"postback", "payload":"in_developing" } ] }, {
>   "title":"Взаємодія з сайтом", "type":"nested", "call_to_actions":[ {
>   "title":"Пошук в ЄДРСР", "type":"postback", "payload" : "search_edrsr"
>   }, { "title":"Статус замовлення", "type":"postback", "payload" :
>   "status_order" }, { "title":"Авторизація", "type":"postback",
>   "payload" : "authorization" }, ] }, { "title":

Куда девается остальной кусок строки?
Если в строке "кирилицу" заменить "латиницей" - то приходит вся строка.

Comment: `mb_strlen` попробуйте.

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое:(

Comment: вообще похоже наоборот надо было предлагать делать :) а этот заголовок обязательный вообще?

Comment: @teran Спасибо, помогло. Как то не подумал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал строчку `'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)`, все заработало

Comment: Полагаю, проблему можно было решить, заменив это такой строкой `'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($data_string, 'UTF-8')`.